# Windows Explorer /select Mac Finder Equivalent?

Tags: java, windows, macos, explorer, finder

```
Explorer /select,C:\MyFolder\MyFile.txt
```

The above command, when executed on Windows, opens the MyFolder directory and selects (highlights) the file called "MyFile.txt".

I have a Java application which utilizes this command to let users know that a file is important, but I would like to make this feature cross-system compatible.  What is the equivalent of this command on Unix operating systems such as Mac OSX and Linux?

Comment: On Linux it would depend on the window manager or file browser they are using.

Comment: I've received a response for how to do this in Linux, over on a question at askubuntu. http://askubuntu.com/questions/133597/reveal-file-in-file-explorer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**For Mac** you can use `open -R filename`

From [open's manual](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html):

> -R  Reveals the file(s) in the Finder instead of opening them.

Comment: Thanks! Far simpler than I expected.

Comment: I didn't know it exists (not in win and not in mac) until you asked the question, so thank you too!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about selecting an item, but using "/usr/bin/open /Users/foobar/Documents/" would at least open a Finder window with the Documents directory active.

Comment: well, learned something myself here as well (the `-R` Binyamin mentioned). Sadly, I don't think the open command exists on Linux, nor if there is something equivalent there.

Comment: I searched for around half an hour earlier, but I couldn't find anything that wasn't specific to different file explorer applications.  I'm going to head over to Ask Ubuntu with this specific question.